# Need help to repair an class that will generate a radio group

Tags: php, class, properties, constructor, undefined

I want to generate an radio group with the last option an radio button with input field text this class must also generate radio group without this input field if needed. This is the class:

```
class Radio extends \PFBC\OptionElement {
    protected $_attributes = array("type" => "radio", "class" => "custom");
    protected $inline;
        protected $_hasOtherTextfield;

  public function __construct($label, $name, $properties, $hasOtherTextfield) {
    $this->_hasOtherTextfield = $hasOtherTextField;
    parent::__construct($label, $name, $properties);
  }

    public function render() { 
        $labelClass = $this->_attributes["type"];
        if(!empty($this->inline))
            $labelClass .= " inline";

        $count = 0;
        foreach($this->options as $value => $text) {
            $value = $this->getOptionValue($value);

            echo '<div class="radio"><label class="form-control', $labelClass . '"> <input id="', $this->_attributes["id"], '-', $count, '"', $this->getAttributes(array("id", "value", "checked")), ' value="', $this->filter($value), '"';
            if(isset($this->_attributes["value"]) && $this->_attributes["value"] == $value)
                echo ' checked="checked"';
            echo '/> ', $text, ' </label></div> ';
            ++$count;
        }   

    if ($this->hasOtherTextField) {
    echo '<div class="radio"><label class="form-control', $labelClass . '"> <input id="', $this->_attributes["id"], '-', $count, '"', $this->getAttributes(array("id", "value", "checked")), ' value="', $this->filter($value), '"';
            if(isset($this->_attributes["value"]) && $this->_attributes["value"] == $value)
                echo ' checked="checked"';
            echo '/> ', $text, ' </label></div>';

      echo '<input type="text" name=""/>';
    }
    }
}
```

And this is the `OptionElement` class:

```
abstract class OptionElement extends Element {
    protected $options;

    public function __construct($label, $name, array $options, array $properties = null) {
        $this->options = $options;
        if(!empty($this->options) && array_values($this->options) === $this->options)
            $this->options = array_combine($this->options, $this->options);

        parent::__construct($label, $name, $properties);
    }

    protected function getOptionValue($value) {
        $position = strpos($value, ":pfbc");
        if($position !== false) {
            if($position == 0)
                $value = "";
            else
                $value = substr($value, 0, $position);
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

And here I generate the radio group:

```
$form->addElement(new Element\Radio("My Selected Radio Buttons", "Radio", array("Option #1", "test"),  true //this will be the last option to generate radio with input));
```

So in this code I have an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hasOtherTextField in
```

and

```
Notice: Undefined property: PFBC\Element\Radio::$hasOtherTextField
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small mistakes in class Radio tmethod render.

**First error** (variable names are case sensitive!):

Use

```
$this->_hasOtherTextfield = $hasOtherTextfield;
```

Instead of

```
$this->_hasOtherTextfield = $hasOtherTextField;
```

**Second error** (wrong variable name):
Use

```
if ($hasOtherTextField) { ... }
```

Or

```
if ($this->_hasOtherTextField) { ... }
```

Instead of

```
if ($this->hasOtherTextField) {
```

Comment: Just found that mistake now and corrected `if ($this->_hasOtherTextfield) {` but one more problem remains: `Notice: Undefined variable: hasOtherTextField in`

Comment: Sounds like I provided a corect answer ;-)

Comment: Yes the second error is gone but the first error remains the one with Undefined :(

Comment: OK. Please add information which line is causing that error.

Comment: The line is `$this->_hasOtherTextfield = $hasOtherTextField;` the one between `public function __construct` and  `parent::__construct`  from `class Radio`

Comment: Updated my answer.